# R: Is it possible to write a condition like "if this statement does not throw an error"

Tags: r

I am using a function called **curve_intersect** under the package **reconPlots** to figure out whether two plotted lines intersect and what the intersection coordinates are. This is a link to the function: https://rdrr.io/github/andrewheiss/reconPlots/src/R/curve_intersect.R

Depending on what the line is, the function can throw an error if there are no points of intersection.

This is an example of a line which would throw an error:

```
line1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2), y = c(1000,750))
line2 <- data.frame(x<-c(1,2,3,4), y = y<-c(60,90,800,1000))
curve_intersect(line1, line2)
```

And an example of one that would return the points of intersection:

```
line1 <- data.frame(x = c(1,2,3,4), y = c(1000,750,200,100))
line2 <- data.frame(x<-c(1,2,3,4), y = y<-c(60,90,800,1000))
curve_intersect(line1, line2)
```

I am writing a function where I would like to run a statement only if there is a point of intersection. i.e. I would like to run it if curve_intersect(line1, line2) does not throw an error.

Is there a simple way to run something only if it doesn't throw an error or is there another way I could run my code only if there is an intersection?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12195574/16730940

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `tryCatch()`. Here is an example which won't stop the code, but will print the error:

```
tryCatch(curve_intersect(line1, line2),
         error = function(e) print(e))
```

To further answer your question, you could return NULL when the function fails. If the `curve_intersect()` does not fail and does not return NULL, run what is inside the conditional statement:

```
c_i <- tryCatch(curve_intersect(line1, line2),
                error = function(e) NULL)

if (!is.null(c_i)) {
  fun()
}
```